# Is "Africa" by Toto focused on the woman referred to in the beginning of the song, or on Africa itself?

Tags: song-lyrics, toto

The song "Africa" by Toto is at least nominally about the narrator's relationship with a woman:

> I hear the drums echoing tonight
>   But she hears only whispers of some quiet conversation
>   **She's coming in 12:30 flight**

However, much of the rest of the song is talking about Africa itself (e.g. the title, the references to wild dogs, etc.). Even its [music video](https://youtu.be/FTQbiNvZqaY) is full of references to Africa (clothing style, globe centered on Africa, etc.), and doesn't feature a woman anywhere in it.

The song includes the following chorus, sung multiple times:

> It's gonna take a lot to drag me away from you
>   There's nothing that a hundred men or more could ever
>   do
>   **I bless the rains down in Africa**

Who, exactly, is "you" here? Is the narrator referring to the woman introduced in the beginning of the song, or to Africa itself?

Comment: Or possibly, both?